# why is apache dead?

Tags: apache2, lamp

I have been developing under Docker but I am running out of time and want to develop directly on my local laptop. I think I need to install LAMP first. The first step is to get apache running, but as you can see it is dead. What to do?

```
richb201@richb201-XPS-13-9370:~$ sudo service apache2 status
[sudo] password for richb201: 
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; disabled; vendor preset:
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you running? Try `journalctl -u apache2` and see `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

Comment: Have you tried ... starting it?

Comment: I followed the install instructs and didn't realize that I needed to start it to.  works great. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian (and in turn, Ubuntu and family) generally enable and start services automatically upon installation. For some reason, the `apache2` service is disabled  in your installation. (The output shown doesn't include the vendor preset, so we can't tell if you disabled it or it came disabled.) So, you need to start it manually:

```
sudo systemctl start apache2.service
```

And enable it if you want it to start on reboot:

```
sudo systemctl enable apache2.service
```

Or, combined:

```
sudo systemctl enable --now apache2.service
```